# open_file() does not work when all views are closed

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to open a file from a filepath but this doesn't work when all views are closed.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class OpenFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run():
        sublime.active_window().open_file('**my_file_path**')
```

I need to open a new file (Ctrl+N) before I can run the command successfully.
When there are 1 or more files already open this command works without a problem.

Also, if there are no files open **but the console is opened**, the command also works.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure how your plugin is running under certain conditions, but your `run` method is missing a  `self` argument. Here's a corrected version of what you have posted (tested in build 3061)

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class TestOpen(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.open_file("**file**")
```